# How do I update a row in the database with the data from website?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to assigned each student with a company from a drop down list and have it updated in the database under the correct student.

So basically, this is how my website looks like.

```
___________________________________________________________________
| Student ID    | Admin No     | Student Name  | Company List     |
|   1           | 1234         | ABC           | <drop down list> |
|   2           | 2345         | BCD           | <drop down list> |
|   3           | 3456         | CDE           | <drop down list> |
|   4           | 4567         | DEF           | <drop down list> |
```

And this is the codes for the table above.

```
<form name="IT" action="getIT_now.php" method="post">

    <table cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>Admin Number</th>
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>GPA</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Company List</th>
            </tr>

<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("....","....","....",".....");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

//create the query
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT student_id, admin_no, name, GPA, gender FROM student_details WHERE jobscope1= 'Information Technology' ORDER BY `GPA` DESC; ");
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT job_title FROM job_details WHERE jobscope='Information Technology' ORDER BY `job_title` ASC;");

        /*options sections start*/
            $options= '';
            while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
            {
                $options .='<option value="'. $row2['job_title'] .'"> '. $row2['job_title'] .'</option>';
            }
            /*options sections end*/

            //return the array and loop through each row
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {

            $studentid = $row['student_id'];
            $adminno = $row['admin_no'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $gpa = $row['GPA'];
            $gender = $row['gender'];

                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td>" . $studentid . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $adminno . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $gpa . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $gender . "</td>"; 
                  echo "<td><select name='ddl' onclick='if(this.value != '') { myform.submit(); }'>".$options."</select></td>";
              }
          echo "</tr>";
?>
</table>
<input type='submit' value='Submit Pick' />
</form>
```

Now this form will actually go to another page since I have include a form action. 
So the codes in this getIT_now.php page is

```
<?
    $con=mysqli_connect("...","....","....","....");
        if (!$con)
        {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_errno());
        }


$ddlvalues = $_POST['ddl'];
$studentid = $_POST['student_id'];
$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO student_details(company) VALUES('" . $ddlvalues . "');");
?>
```

However, when I check the database, only the first option in the drop down list is reflected in a new row. I have tried to use the UPDATE query statement, but it is wrong.

This is the query for the UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE student_details SET company = '" . $ddlvalues . "' WHERE student_id = '" . $studentid . "';
```

The problem I'm having right now is actually:

- How do I make Student ID on the website and in the database to match so that it can update correctly?
- Why is it that only the first option in the drop down list is reflected when I use the INSERT query?

I am quite new to PHP so I am really struggling with this.

Comment: Because you are inserting only one statement and that is not in a loop.

Comment: At the moment, you're wonderfully open to SQL Injection.  You should be using parameterized queries

Comment: @ArunKumar which one statement are you referring to? and which loop am i suppose to use? for loop? while loop?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse what you mean by using parameterised queries?

Comment: @Angelica I suppose there is only one insert statement mentioned by you and I am evidently saying that.

Comment: ...seriously?  [5 seconds in Bing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_query).  For more help, look at a **lot** of questions here and Security.SE

Comment: @ArunKumar okay so how do I use a loop for that insert query? while or for loop?

Comment: Any loop for that matter is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an input that holds the student_id, i.e `$_POST['student_id']` is not set, also you would have to validate the user inputs before you pass them to query, You can use prepared statements,

Try with a hidden field like

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="'.$studentid.'"/>';
```

Comment: I have included the hidden fields, but why is it still not updating in the database?

Comment: I am using this as the update statement.

UPDATE student_details SET company = '" . $ddlvalues . "' WHERE student_id = '" . $studentid . "';